# Windowing is not triggered when we deployed the Flink application into Kinesis Data Analytics

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

We have an Apache Flink POC application which works fine locally but after we deploy into Kinesis Data Analytics (KDA) it does not emit records into the sink.

### Used technologies

#### Local

- Source: Kafka 2.7

  - 1 broker
  - 1 topic with partition of 1 and replication factor 1
- Processing: Flink 1.12.1
- Sink: Managed ElasticSearch Service 7.9.1 (the same instance as in case of AWS)

#### AWS

- Source: Amazon MSK Kafka 2.8

  - 3 brokers (but we are connecting to one)
  - 1 topic with partition of 1, replication factor 3
- Processing: Amazon KDA Flink 1.11.1

  - Parallelism: 2
  - Parallelism per KPU: 2
- Sink: Managed ElasticSearch Service 7.9.1

### Application logic

1. The `FlinkKafkaConsumer` reads messages in json format from the topic
2. The jsons are mapped to domain objects, called `Telemetry`

```
private static DataStream<Telemetry> SetupKafkaSource(StreamExecutionEnvironment environment){
    Properties kafkaProperties = new Properties();
    kafkaProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "BROKER1_ADDRESS.amazonaws.com:9092");
    kafkaProperties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "flink_consumer");

    FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("THE_TOPIC", new SimpleStringSchema(), kafkaProperties);

    consumer.setStartFromEarliest(); //Just for repeatable testing

    return environment
            .addSource(consumer)
            .map(new MapJsonToTelemetry());
}
```

3. The Telemetry’s timestamp is chosen for EventTimeStamp.
   3.1.    With `forMonotonousTimeStamps`
4. Telemetry’s `StateIso` is used for `keyBy`.
   4.1.    The two letter iso code of the state of USA
5. 5 seconds tumbling window strategy is applied

```
private static SingleOutputStreamOperator<StateAggregatedTelemetry> SetupProcessing(DataStream<Telemetry> telemetries) {
    WatermarkStrategy<Telemetry> wmStrategy =
            WatermarkStrategy
                    .<Telemetry>forMonotonousTimestamps()
                    .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.TimeStamp);

    return telemetries
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(wmStrategy)
            .keyBy(t -> t.StateIso)
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
            .process(new WindowCountFunction());
}
```

6. A custom `ProcessWindowFunction` is called to perform some basic aggregation.
   6.1.    We calculate a single `StateAggregatedTelemetry`
7. ElasticSearch is configured as sink.
   7.1.    `StateAggregatedTelemetry` data are mapped into a `HashMap` and pushed into `source`.
   7.2.    All `setBulkFlushXYZ` methods are set to low values

```
private static void SetupElasticSearchSink(SingleOutputStreamOperator<StateAggregatedTelemetry> telemetries) {
    List<HttpHost> httpHosts = new ArrayList<>();
    httpHosts.add(HttpHost.create("https://ELKCLUSTER_ADDRESS.amazonaws.com:443"));

    ElasticsearchSink.Builder<StateAggregatedTelemetry> esSinkBuilder = new ElasticsearchSink.Builder<>(
            httpHosts,
            (ElasticsearchSinkFunction<StateAggregatedTelemetry>) (element, ctx, indexer) -> {
                Map<String, Object> record = new HashMap<>();

                record.put("stateIso", element.StateIso);
                record.put("healthy", element.Flawless);
                record.put("unhealthy", element.Faulty);
                ...

                LOG.info("Telemetry has been added to the buffer");
                indexer.add(Requests.indexRequest()
                        .index("INDEXPREFIX-"+ from.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")))
                        .source(record, XContentType.JSON));
            }
    );

    //Using low values to make sure that the Flush will happen
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxActions(25);
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushInterval(1000);
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushMaxSizeMb(1);
    esSinkBuilder.setBulkFlushBackoff(true);
    esSinkBuilder.setRestClientFactory(restClientBuilder -> {});

    LOG.info("Sink has been attached to the DataStream");
    telemetries.addSink(esSinkBuilder.build());
}
```

### Excluded things

- We managed to put Kafka, KDA and ElasticSearch under the same VPC and same subnets to avoid the need to sign each request
- From the logs we could see that the Flink can reach the ES cluster.
  Request

```json
{
    "locationInformation": "org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.verifyClientConnection(Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge.java:135)",
    "logger": "org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.elasticsearch7.Elasticsearch7ApiCallBridge",
    "message": "Pinging Elasticsearch cluster via hosts [https://...es.amazonaws.com:443] ...",
    "threadName": "Window(TumblingEventTimeWindows(5000), EventTimeTrigger, WindowCountFunction) -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/2)",
    "applicationARN": "arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:...",
    "applicationVersionId": "39",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "messageType": "INFO"
}
```

Response

```json
{
    "locationInformation": "org.elasticsearch.client.RequestLogger.logResponse(RequestLogger.java:59)",
    "logger": "org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient",
    "message": "request [HEAD https://...es.amazonaws.com:443/] returned [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]",
    "threadName": "Window(TumblingEventTimeWindows(5000), EventTimeTrigger, WindowCountFunction) -> (Sink: Print to Std. Out, Sink: Unnamed, Sink: Print to Std. Out) (2/2)",
    "applicationARN": "arn:aws:kinesisanalytics:...",
    "applicationVersionId": "39",
    "messageSchemaVersion": "1",
    "messageType": "DEBUG"
}
```

- We could also verify that the messages had been read from the Kafka topic and sent for processing by looking at the Flink Dashboard
  [image: Data is sent and received between tasks]

### What we have tried without luck

- We had implemented a `RichParallelSourceFunction` which emits 1_000_000 messages and then exits

  - This worked well in the Local environment
  - The job finished in the AWS environment, but there was no data on the sink side
- We had implemented an other `RichParallelSourceFunction` which emits 100 messages at each second

  - Basically we had two loops a `while(true)` outer and `for` inner
  - After the inner loop we called the `Thread.sleep(1000)`
  - This worked perfectly fine on the local environment
  - But in AWS we could see that checkpoints' size grow continuously and no message appeared in ELK
- We have tried to run the KDA application with different parallelism settings

  - But there was no difference
- We also tried to use different watermarking strategies (`forBoundedOutOfOrderness`, `withIdle`, `noWatermarks`)

  - But there was no difference
- We have added logs for the `ProcessWindowFunction` and for the `ElasticsearchSinkFunction`

  - Whenever we run the application from IDEA then these logs were on the console
  - Whenever we run the application with KDA then there was no such logs in CloudWatch

    - Those logs that were added to the `main` they do appear in the CloudWatch logs

---

We suppose that we don't see data on the sink side because the window processing logic is not triggered. That's why don't see processing logs in the CloudWatch.

Any help would be more than welcome!

---

**Update #1**

- We have tried to downgrade the Flink version from 1.12.1 to 1.11.1

  - There is no change
- We have tried processing time window instead of event time

  - It did not even work on the local environment

---

**Update #2**

The average message size is around 4kb. Here is an excerpt of a sample message:

```json
{
  "affiliateCode": "...",
  "appVersion": "1.1.14229",
  "clientId": "guid",
  "clientIpAddr": "...",
  "clientOriginated": true,
  "connectionType": "Cable/DSL",
  "countryCode": "US",
  "design": "...",
  "device": "...",
  ...
  "deviceSerialNumber": "...",
  "dma": "UNKNOWN",
  "eventSource": "...",
  "firstRunTimestamp": 1609091112818,
  "friendlyDeviceName": "Comcast",
  "fullDevice": "Comcast ...",
  "geoInfo": {
    "continent": {
      "code": "NA",
      "geoname_id": 120
    },
    "country": {
      "geoname_id": 123,
      "iso_code": "US"
    },
    "location": {
      "accuracy_radius": 100,
      "latitude": 37.751,
      "longitude": -97.822,
      "time_zone": "America/Chicago"
    },
    "registered_country": {
      "geoname_id": 123,
      "iso_code": "US"
    }
  },
  "height": 720,
  "httpUserAgent": "Mozilla/...",
  "isLoggedIn": true,
  "launchCount": 19,
  "model": "...",
  "os": "Comcast...",
  "osVersion": "...",
  ...
  "platformTenantCode": "...",
  "productCode": "...",
  "requestOrigin": "https://....com",
  "serverTimeUtc": 1617809474787,
  "serviceCode": "...",
  "serviceOriginated": false,
  "sessionId": "guid",
  "sessionSequence": 2,
  "subtype": "...",
  "tEventId": "...",
  ...
  "tRegion": "us-east-1",
  "timeZoneOffset": 5,
  "timestamp": 1617809473305,
  "traits": {
    "isp": "Comcast Cable",
    "organization": "..."
  },
  "type": "...",
  "userId": "guid",
  "version": "v1",
  "width": 1280,
  "xb3traceId": "guid"
}
```

We are using `ObjectMapper` to parse only just some of the fields of the json. Here is how the `Telemetry` class looks like:

```
public class Telemetry {
    public String AppVersion;
    public String CountryCode;
    public String ClientId;
    public String DeviceSerialNumber;
    public String EventSource;
    public String SessionId;
    public TelemetrySubTypes SubType; //enum
    public String TRegion;
    public Long TimeStamp;
    public TelemetryTypes Type; //enum
    public String StateIso;
    
    ...
}
```

---

**Update #3**

### Source

#### Subtasks tab

| ID | Bytes received | Records received | Bytes sent | Records sent | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 B | 0 | 0 B | 0 | RUNNING |
| 1 | 0 B | 0 | 2.83 MB | 15,000 | RUNNING |

#### Watermarks tab

No Data

### Window

#### Subtasks tab

| ID | Bytes received | Records received | Bytes sent | Records sent | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.80 MB | 9,501 | 0 B | 0 | RUNNING |
| 1 | 1.04 MB | 5,499 | 0 B | 0 | RUNNING |

#### Watermarks

| SubTask | Watermark |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | No Watermark |
| 2 | No Watermark |

Comment: Can You drop just a sample of data You are reading from Kafka ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński I've extended my question. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Few more things to ask, have You checked the watermarks generated by the first operators parallel instances ? Did You also check how much data each operator instance has sent ? (both visible in UI)

Comment: @DominikWosiński I've extended my question with the related information. It seems quite strange for me that there is no watermark.

Comment: Yeah, so my first idea is that it is due to incorrect parallelism/partitions relation, You've said You tested it with different parallelism but not sure if You tried parallelism of 1.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @DominikWosiński It turned out that we had made a really basic mistake, forgot to set the time characteristics. I've placed a post where I've detailed the problem if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a support session with the AWS folks it turned out that we have missed to set the time characteristic on the streaming environment.

- In 1.11.1 the default value of `TimeCharacteristic` was `IngestionTime`.
- Since 1.12.1 (see related [release notes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/release-notes/flink-1.12/#flip-134-batch-execution-for-the-datastream-api)) the default value is `EventTime`:

> In Flink 1.12 the default stream time characteristic has been changed to EventTime, thus you don’t need to call this method for enabling event-time support anymore.

So, after we have set that `EventTime` explicitly then it started to generates watermarks like a charm:

```
streamingEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

According the comments and more information You have provided, it seems that the issue is the fact that two Flink consumers can't consume from the same partition. So, in Your case only one parallel instance of the operator will consume from kafka partition and the other one will be idle.

In general Flink operator will select `MIN([all_downstream_parallel_watermarks])`, so In Your case one Kafka Consumer will produce normal Watermarks and the other will never produce anything (flink assumes `Long.Min` in that case), so Flink will select the lower one which is `Long.Min`. So, window will never be fired, because while the data is flowing one of the watermarks is never generated. The good practice is to use the same paralellism as the number of Kafka partitions when working with Kafka.

Comment: I've changed the parallelism to 1 as you have suggested (so there is only a single subtask). The source operator's Watermarks tab still says *No Data*. The window operator's Watermarks tab still says *No Watermark*.